# Separating Facebook App Insights

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a PHP app that uses the graph API to post videos and photos to a users timeline.

We can gather all insights for the app which is great but need a way to separate them based on which customer is making use of our service. We we use the graph API to gather the insights.

Can this be done?

Comment: I don’t think so – the concept of a “customer” does not exist in terms of API. (Or do you mean the actual user who’s timeline the post are made on with “customer”?)

Comment: Exactly that. Think of it like us letting people make their own websites and using our Facebook app to let their users share items to Facebook. Can we tag each share so that we can pull that data from Facebook and report back

Comment: No, you can not “tag” – you are not allowed to pre-fill or modify the user message of any post or share in any way. It would really be the best solution to use separate apps for this.